# LDAP Query to get all groups for a user using LDAP template

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

How can I do a LDAP query to get all the groups a user is in given a username?

This is what I have:

```
Public Set<LdapGroup> getGroups(String username) {
LdapQuery query = LdapQueryBuilder.query()
        .searchScope(SearchScope.SUBTREE)
        .attributes(“cn”)
        .where(“objectclass=groups”).is(“groupOfUniqueNames”);

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate();
List<LdapGroup> results = ldapTemplate.find(query, LdapGroup.class);
Return results 
}
```

It’s not returning anything and I’m new to LDAP